# I need to duplicate software packages installed on one HP-UX system to a test system

Tags: mirror, hp-ux

I am very inexperienced with HP-UX and need to duplicate a production server for a test environment.  I have 11.11 on the prod server and have completed the base install on the test server.  What I need is a way to add the installed packages from the prod server to the test server.  Unfortunately I haven't the foggiest idea how to do this.

I've thought of using ignite backup and restore but don't have matching tape types between the two.  The other thought was using swlist to gather the installed packages and then going to the website to download and install on the test environment.

Has anyone successfully done something like this?

Pointers?

Answer (score 0):

A common technique from the past was to restore a backup from the Production server on to a machine in a lab environment. From there, the configuration can be altered to meet the needs of the new networking environment.

Comment: I've considered this and may end up going that route but I am really looking to match packages only.  I've got space considerations on the test system and mismatched tape technology that prevents this method from being painless in our environment.